# cannot get include(dirname(__FILE__) . "/dir/file.php"); to work

Tags: php

Okay, so I'm having an issue with one of my includes. My `config.php` includes a file called `user.php` which is in classes directory. If I call the `config.php` file from a different directory, relative paths get broken.

I tried using

```
include(dirname(__FILE__) . "/classes/user.php");
```

and

```
include __DIR__ . '../classes/user.php';
```

instead of

```
include('../classes/user.php');
```

in my `config.php` file and it still gives me a cannot file or directory error. It keeps looking for user.php in includes/classes/user.php instead of going up a directory. I've tried the dirname way both with `../` and without the slash. Nothing seems to work.

To clarify, my structure looks like this:

```
-admin
-classes
--user.php
-css
-drop
--index.php
-img
-includes
--config.php
-js
index.php
etc.
```

config.php requires classes/user.php. I get an issue when I try to include config.php in the drop/index.php file. It can't find the classes/user.php.

Comment: what do you get when you `var_dump(dirname(__FILE__) . "/classes/user.php")` ?

Comment: It returns this: string(49) "C:\xampp\htdocs\darkerslate\drop/classes/user.php"

Comment: try:  `is_file(dirname(__FILE__) . "/classes/user.php")) or die('file not exists');`  first.

Comment: If your `config.php` file is in your root you should be able to `define("ROOTDIR",__DIR__);` and use `ROOTDIR.'/classes/user.php'` provided the class include comes after the define and your `config.php` is the first `include()` on your script page....this what I do anyway...

Comment: The config.php is here includes/config.php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have tried to add a backslash before two dots (..)? Like this

```
include(dirname(__FILE__) . "/../classes/user.php");
```

Just want to try to help you.

Comment: That did it! Thank you. It's always something so simple like that, isn't it?

Comment: anytime, I use linux and this happen many time because the system read full path like this /opt/lampp/htdocs/project/class../class.php if I don't add a slash before two dots. So we need correct full path like /opt/lampp/htdocs/project/class/../class.php

Comment: I would upvote you but I have a low reputation because I ask questions that other people think are stupid, you know, so I can get a better understanding of php, etc.

Comment: No problem Janden :), glad I could help you.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, try something like this:

```
include($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . "/classes/user.php");
```

UPDATE, if `../` and the above doesnt work either, try this:

```
 include(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . "/classes/user.php");
```

Comment: I get this: Warning: include(localhost/classes/user.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\darkerslate\includes\config.php on line 35

Comment: I see.. btw, ive also tried `../` on my local environment and it works.

Comment: what error do you get when you run it like this: `include("../classes/user.php");`

Comment: I get the same exact error as two comments above. I get that error for all of the methods I tried in my OP. It only works if I move the file into the home directory, that way the relative path is good to go.

Comment: there might be something wrong in your structure.. if you want I can try helping you remotely through teamviewer, let me know.